# How to use a custom Login Page (Not Windows Login Box) for Windows Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sharepoint-2007

Is there any way to use a custom Login Page (Not Windows Login Box) for Windows Authentication of SharePoint publishing sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use custom login page but still authenticate with Active Directory users take a look at these:

[FormsAuthentication with Active Directory (C#)](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Forms-Authentication-Active-Directory.aspx)

[FormsAuthentication with Active Directory (VB.NET)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340)

Answer (score 1):

This is possible and I just recently implemented a hybrid approach following [this tutorial](http://bit.ly/gFbFnt).  It's not a short snippet of code and it is a little more complex than can be shown here.

Comment: Of course this approach does a lot more than what is asked for in this question. But as far as I can tell from looking at the article the site still shows the standard browser login dialog for intranet users. Is this not the case?